# Horizontal Scroll problem on basic html css Website

Tags: html, css

For a few days I am trying to eliminate the horizontal scroll on the website, but I am unable to do so. Here is the codepen for it: https://codepen.io/170mayank/pen/gOXExag

This is a simple website code made of basic HTML & CSS and only has two sections. I am making it mobile-first, but the problem is in all screen sizes. Sorry for the bad code, I am a total beginner to web dev. I also haven't uploaded the images, as they don't matter.

I have tried my best to solve the issue but was unsuccessful at it :(. Your help would be highly appreciated.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

body{
   font-family: gimlet-text, serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #344559;
   min-height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
}

/* Hero Section */

.sec1{
    background-color: #F7F6F4;
}

.sec1__wrap{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 15px;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.sec1__wrap__img{
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.sec1__wrap__h1{
    font-size: 48.83px;
    font-family: balboa, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 25px 0 15px 0;
}

.sec1__wrap__p{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sec1__wrap__wrap{
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
}

.sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 8px;
    background-color: #F9826A;
    padding: 10px 20px;

}

.sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1__text{
    font-size: 12.8px;
    color: #F7F6F4;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* .sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1__img{
    
} */

.sec1__wrap__wrap__btn2{
    font-size: 12.8px;
    color: #F9826A;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* Section Separator */

.separator{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}

/* Website Section 2: Services */

.sec2{
    background-color: #F7F6F4;
}

.sec2__wrap{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px 15px;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; */
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__h3{
    font-size: 31.25px;
    font-family: balboa, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__dash{
    width: 100px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #F9826A;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__p{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap{
    background-color: #F9826A;
    gap: 10px;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap__p{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/btg4pzb.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="sec1">
        <div class="sec1__wrap">
            <img src="/Images/1. Home/hero.jpg" class="sec1__wrap__img">
            <h1 class="sec1__wrap__h1">The Best Freight Solution Company</h1>
            <p class="sec1__wrap__p">We provide the most specialized and helpful experience by removing hassle associated with your transportation needs.</p>
            <div class="sec1__wrap__wrap">
                <a href="#"><div class="sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1">
                    <p class="sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1__text">Contact Us Today!</p>
                    <img src="/Images/1. Home/hero mail.svg" class="sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1__img">
                </div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="sec1__wrap__wrap__btn2">Apply for job</div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    <section class="sec2">
        <div class="sec2__wrap">
            <div class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap box1">
                <img class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__img" src="/Images/1. Home/image1.jpg">
                <h3 class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__h3">Freight Transportation</h3>
                <div class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__dash"></div>
                <p class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__p">Our company specializes in delivery across multi road transportation platform while providing most competitive rates in the industry.</p>
                <div class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap__p">Request a Quote</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap__img" src="/Images/1. Home/arrow1.svg">
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see any horizontal scroll at all.

Comment: Here is the [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S7S_0ULWO90YZ_kWodj7wdZZsxEd9QkN/view?usp=sharing). Please have a look.

Comment: It appears that the width on the body element should 100% instead of 100vw because the vertical scroll bar causes the need for the horizontal scroll bar since it takes from the width.  Change it to 100% and the horizontal scroll bar disappears.

Comment: Hiding the horizontal overflow will result in you page content not being centered  horizontally.

Comment: I have tried making width at 100% on codepen, it's not working. If you can try making the changes, then it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use overflow css property.
Give.

```
overflow:'hidden'
```

In you css file on body it will eliminate scroll
[You can read documentation of mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Overflow)

**EDIT**.`overflow-x: hidden;` its work  fore me
[image: see screenshot]

**EDIT2**

```
.separator {
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background-color: #D5D5D5;
}
```

instead of width 100vw here give 100%

Comment: I have tried it, but for some reason, it's not working. If possible, please try fixing the problem. It would really be helpful.

Comment: Did you try overflow-x:'hidden'? With ! important?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. But I don't know if I am doing it correctly, as it's not working.

Comment: see my edit it work for me if its not working you can try width 100% and overflow hidden simultaneously

Comment: i found the main cause it was .seperator class you give it width 100vw change its to 100%

Comment: its my pleasure. you can still tick it green . i did not get it what you are trying to say :-)

Comment: @Zeeshan they were saying that they accidentally used 100vw instead of 100% for the .seperator class

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that you use `width: 100vw;` for `body` and `.seperator` class. Just change them as `width: 100%;`.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

body{
   font-family: gimlet-text, serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #344559;
   min-height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}

/* Hero Section */

.sec1{
    background-color: #F7F6F4;
}

.sec1__wrap{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 15px;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.sec1__wrap__img{
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.sec1__wrap__h1{
    font-size: 48.83px;
    font-family: balboa, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 25px 0 15px 0;
}

.sec1__wrap__p{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sec1__wrap__wrap{
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
}

.sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 8px;
    background-color: #F9826A;
    padding: 10px 20px;

}

.sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1__text{
    font-size: 12.8px;
    color: #F7F6F4;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* .sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1__img{
    
} */

.sec1__wrap__wrap__btn2{
    font-size: 12.8px;
    color: #F9826A;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* Section Separator */

.separator{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}

/* Website Section 2: Services */

.sec2{
    background-color: #F7F6F4;
}

.sec2__wrap{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px 15px;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; */
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__h3{
    font-size: 31.25px;
    font-family: balboa, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__dash{
    width: 100px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #F9826A;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__p{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap{
    background-color: #F9826A;
    gap: 10px;
}

.sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap__p{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/btg4pzb.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="sec1">
        <div class="sec1__wrap">
            <img src="/Images/1. Home/hero.jpg" class="sec1__wrap__img">
            <h1 class="sec1__wrap__h1">The Best Freight Solution Company</h1>
            <p class="sec1__wrap__p">We provide the most specialized and helpful experience by removing hassle associated with your transportation needs.</p>
            <div class="sec1__wrap__wrap">
                <a href="#"><div class="sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1">
                    <p class="sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1__text">Contact Us Today!</p>
                    <img src="/Images/1. Home/hero mail.svg" class="sec1__wrap__wrap__btn1__img">
                </div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="sec1__wrap__wrap__btn2">Apply for job</div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    <section class="sec2">
        <div class="sec2__wrap">
            <div class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap box1">
                <img class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__img" src="/Images/1. Home/image1.jpg">
                <h3 class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__h3">Freight Transportation</h3>
                <div class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__dash"></div>
                <p class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__p">Our company specializes in delivery across multi road transportation platform while providing most competitive rates in the industry.</p>
                <div class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap__p">Request a Quote</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="sec2__wrap__box-wrap__btn-wrap__img" src="/Images/1. Home/arrow1.svg">
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much George for your help for fixing the problem :)

Comment: Good! You're welcome!